# PHP document does not see the "require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';"

Tags: php, azure, composer-php, dreamweaver

- I have downloaded Composer and followed the instructions on the
  following link https://getcomposer.org/download/.
- I have coded my PHP document and set the `require_once __DIR__ .    '/composer/autoload_real.php';` as per the directory
  `C:\wamp64\www\TastefullyObscene\Mailing\sendgrid-php\vendor\autoload.php`.

  - All I get in Dreamweaver are the blatantly rubbish error messages of the illustrated:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI8R4.png)

I do not see what is wrong here, apart from the instructions clearly are inaccurate. What I am I missing here exactly?

*I also want to add: by all means feel free to ask further questions to help you help me, but please do not make random suggestions of "have you tried...?" which turn out not to work. It's really unconstructive and I don't have time to play and experiment with this.
If you've come across this issue yourself and have resolved said issue, then please contribute.*

Many thanks and much appreciated.

Regards

Todd

Comment: did you run composer install in you project

Comment: The path should normally be __DIR__ . ‘/vendor/autoload.php’ (or __DIR__ . ‘/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php’ if you’re combining it with your own autoloader). Those paths will only exist after you’ve run composer install to create your project’s vendor directory.

Comment: I have downloaded the ru n the  **Composer-Setup.exe** & I have run the Command Line installation.

When I come to running this command: **php composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin**, the Command response is 

**The defined install dir (bin) does not exist.**

When it actually does exist, here **C:\wamp64\www\TastefullyObscene\Mailing\sendgrid-php\vendor\bin**

I'm sorry but is this meant to be this impossible just to install a file? Its absolutely bloody ridiculous.

Comment: @RobHogan That is the point, the path does exist, so surely Dreamweaver should just be able to see the file **require_once __DIR__ .    '/composer/autoload_real.php';** [Click here to see the directory on my system](https://imgur.com/a/758sX)

Comment: You’re missing the ‘vendor’ part of the path.

Comment: @robhogan out ot **C:\wamp64\www\TastefullyObscene\Mailing\sendgrid-php\vendor\autoload.php** which bit of the path should I use?

Thanks. Todd :)

Comment: As you can see, the directory is right here...
[View Image](https://imgur.com/a/aiF8w)

Answer (score 1):

The file not found issue is because `composer/autoload_real.php` is inside the `vendor` directory, so for a script in your project root the correct path would be:
`require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php'` (note the `vendor` part, which you're currently missing).

However, this probably isn't the file you want to require, unless you have your own autoloader and want to feed it with paths from composer. Normally, you just let composer be the autoloader by requiring `autoload.php` *instead*:

`require  __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'`

The difference is that `autoload.php` registers an autoloader, whereas `autoload_real.php` returns an array which you can use to register your own.

The composer docs explain this here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading